# Automating JMP Software testing?

Tags: qtp, sas-jmp

We use JMP application for statistical analysis. I am trying to use QTP (record/playback) for this. But it does not work. Once it opens the application and tries to open a file, the JMP application shuts down.
We compare two CSV files and generate matched pair analysis of Mean for various parameters.

Any recommendation on how to proceed?

Comment: Hi Shrungaar,

Could you clarify please?

If you USE an application what are you trying to do with it and QTP?
Do you want to TEST an application with QTP?
Do you want to automate some manual operations with QTP?

Comment: Hi Albert,
here is my scenario. 
27. Open JMP application
28. Open Test data M49 csv file
29. Change column properties for “Source Slot” to numeric - nominal
30. Change column properties for Center Thickness, Mean Thickness, GBIR, Bow and Warp to numeric - continuous
31. Save file as “JMP file
32. Open Reference M49 JMP file and Test M49 JMP file
33. Go to Table\Summary
34. Select “Source Slot” as Group and
35. Center Thickness, Mean Thickness, GBIR, Bow and Warp select “Mean” Statistics and click OK.
36. Repeat step 34 and 35 for Test M49 file.
37. Now go to Table\Join.

Comment: 38. Select Ref and test tables. Click OK
39. Select Analyze\Matched Pairs
40. Select Center Thickness Ref and Center Thickness Test
41. Click OK
42. The matched pair differences should be zero.
43. Save file as Global_M49_Matched Pairs
44. Repeat steps 39 - 43 for rest of the metrics.

these are the steps I am trying to automate using QTP. 
thanks
Tina

Answer (score 1):

If you do not **have** to use the QTP tool for this job, I'd recommend either

1. Automate JMP using OLE automation to produce the results and analysis reports. Look in the JMP install dir under Samples\Automation\ for examples.

or

2. Create a .jsl script file to produce the results and run jmp.exe c:\myscript.jsl and call the JSL `Quit();` function to shut down when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I see from the additional details you provided.

1) It's NOT a test automation job. QTP here is used only as GUI interaction tool. So may be you should consider first tool like ***AutoIt***. It's free, by the way, and also has record/playback capabilities you needed from QTP.

2) Steps 27-41 are routine operations. Step 42 ("The matched pair differences should be zero") is a question, that requires investigation, especially if pair differences ARE NOT zero. How were you going to automate that using record/playback?

Thank you,
Albert Gareev